# Docker base image from my current os configuration

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi-zero

I need some clarifications about Docker Base Os image.

In particular, I'd like to know if it is possible to create a docker base os from the image running on my Raspberry. If I understand correctly, the right way to use docker involves the use of a new installation of the (for instance Raspbian) Os and create the containers that have to be run on top of this clean Os.

By the way, on my Raspbian Os, there are a lot of configurations, and different processes (and so on) developed along the last years.

So, is there any possibility to create a Docker container that reflects my version of the Raspbian Os? And eventually, Do I have to load it normally using the FROM keyword?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can create your own images, which do not have base images. That is called `scratch`.

You still have to start you `Dockerfile` with `FROM scratch` as soon as this is a requirement - to have `FROM` at the beginning:

> The FROM instruction initializes a new build stage and sets the Base
>   Image for subsequent instructions. As such, a valid Dockerfile must
>   start with a FROM instruction.

But in this particular case no real image would be downloaded - it is treated as a reserved word.

This is the source: https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch

Comment: thanks for your very quick response ... I have spent a couple of minutes looking the link that you provided to me. It seems to be the perfect solution to my problem. Anyway, let me ask you one more thing ... Considering a scenario where  I create a container using scratch or some tool such as debootstrap and then, for instance, I share my new base image on a Hub. Can I reuse it in a new container as basic os by explicitly call it in the FROM keyword?

Comment: Yes, of course you can then use this image as base for others

Comment: Thanks a lot... I will try in the next days.

Comment: can you help me? I've spent some other times to better understand docker and its nomenclature. So in particular if I have understood correctly, I have to create a first level image corresponding to my OS and then I can create a second layer image based on this base image. So considering a Dockerfile to do this process I have to do something like `FROM scratch ADD <myos.tar.xz> /` where I manually generate a tar from my Raspbian OS image?

Comment: or maybe can I do something like `FROM scratch COPY / /` where COPY / / I suppose that means copy the whole filesystem

Comment: You are right, you put initial file system as `tar` archive and then perform necessary adaptation with `RUN` commands or whatever. Sop you need to somehow `tar` you current fs. Frankly speaking, I've never have done that, probably good idea would be to use `dd`..